# flutter Debug error Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\lijoj\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\lijoj\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

check if you have any assets is not founded by `pubspec.yaml` maybe for typo you will get Waring for that after packages get

1. flutter clean
2. check your `pubspec.yaml` file
3. flutter packages get

Comment: its not working